# How to properly graph train/val on same graph in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, logging, pytorch

I have the following code that trains a model and stores logs in a results variable

```
import tqdm.notebook as tq
import sys

num_epochs = 10
results = {"train_loss": [], "val_loss": [], "train_acc": [], "val_acc": []}

for epoch in range(1, num_epochs+1):
  sys.stdout.write(f"---Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs}: ")
  epoch_loss = {"train": [], "val": []}
  epoch_acc = {"train": [], "val": []}

  for phase in ['train', 'val']:
    if phase=="train":
      model.train(True)
    else:
      model.train(False)
    
    # most important thing I learned from this project was how to fix tqdm nastiness in colab
    for batch_idx, (x, y) in tq.tqdm(enumerate(dataloaders[phase]),
                                     total=len(dataloaders[phase]),
                                     leave=False):

      # put data to device and get output
      x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
      preds = model(x)

      # calc and log model loss
      batch_loss = criterion(preds, y)
      epoch_loss[phase].append(batch_loss.item())

      # calculate acc and extend to epoch_acc
      preds = torch.argmax(preds, dim=1)
      batch_acc = torch.sum(preds==y)/len(y)
      epoch_acc[phase].append(batch_acc)

      # zero the grad
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # take a step if training mode is on
      if phase=="train":
        batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

  # at the end of each epoch, calculate avg epoch train/val loss/accuracy
  train_loss = sum(epoch_loss["train"])/len(epoch_loss["train"])
  val_loss = sum(epoch_loss["val"])/len(epoch_loss["val"])
  train_acc = 100*sum(epoch_acc["train"])/len(epoch_acc["train"])
  val_acc = 100*sum(epoch_acc["val"])/len(epoch_acc["val"])

  # log losses and accs every epoch
  results['train_loss'].extend(epoch_loss['train'])
  results['train_acc'].extend(epoch_acc['train'])
  results['val_loss'].extend(epoch_loss['val'])
  results['val_acc'].extend(epoch_acc['val'])

  # and print it nicely
  sys.stdout.write("train_loss: {:.4f} train_acc: {:.2f}% ".format(train_loss, train_acc))
  sys.stdout.write("val_loss: {:.4f} val_acc: {:.2f}%\n".format(val_loss, val_acc))
```

I'm logging the avg accuracy and avg loss of every batch into separate training/validation loss/acc arrays. The problem is that I have more training batches so when I try to graph my training logs I get something like this:

[image]
[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What are you expecting the "workaround" to be? Either plot epoch instead of batch scores, or use different plots. Otherwise, you can repeat values on the val plot but that completely beats the purpose of a plot in the first place.

Comment: Also, see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_grad_enabled.html . In validation mode, you can disable gradient and validation will run faster and consume much less memory. Also, you dont need to run optimizer.zero_grad() in validation phase

Answer (score 0):

You are making a few conceptual errors:

1. You are calculating the validation loss/accuracy in multiple batches, as opposed to over the entire validation set
2. You are calculating the validation accuracy for a static model after it has already trained on all the data, as opposed to periodically assessing the validation accuracy **as** it is training

You should average your batch training performance over each epoch, and once per epoch calculate the complete loss/acc statistics across the entire validation set. Then you will have `n_epochs` values for both training and validation and can plot them on the same axes.